# What does the phrase ''as an inseparable whole'' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In this following context, what does the phrase ''as an inseparable whole'' mean?
Is it an extended phrase of ''as an whole''?

Could I have any synonymous?

Thanks to All.

The context:

> If it were really the case that the new individual, as an inseparable
> whole, was begotten by its parents, twins could never exhibit totally
> opposite tendencies.

Source:P. 13
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: Have you looked up 'inseparable' in a dictionary? You suggest that you understand what "as a whole" would mean. What do you think this adjective would add to that phrase?

Comment: The reason for including apparently tautologous ***inseparable*** here isn't really (or *at all*) to add "emphasis". It's to avoid possible confusion between ***as a** whole* (when viewed as a single entity) and ***on the** whole* (on balance, taking everything into account). Particularly because in this *exact* context, the difference between a child being ***completely*** or ***on balance*** a product of its parents is precisely the matter being discussed.